# Highchart on Ruby on Rails 7 only rendering one datapoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am trying to create a basic line chart using HighCharts in Ruby on Rails 7. Following is the script. It only shows one datapoint, whereas, just rendering the json data show all datapoints. I know that the chart is expecting either

1. series: [{name: "a", data: [1]}, {name: "b", data: [2]}]
2. series: [{name: "a", data: [1,2]}]
   but I'm not sure how to pass in these data. Any help would be appreciated.

````
<script>
   Highcharts.chart('chart', {
                yAxis: {
                        title: {
                                text: 'Facts'
                        }
                },
                xAxis: {
                        title: {
                                text: 'Date'
                        },
                        categories: [<%= raw fact.date.to_json %>]
                },
                plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                                label: {
                                        connectorAllowed: false
                                }
                        }
                },
                series: [{
                           name: [<%= raw fact.name.to_json %>], 
                           data: [<%= raw fact.data.to_json %>]
                        }],
        });
</script>```
````

Comment: Hi @ASing, You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Comment: @ppotaczek Yes, thank you. You're right. I moved the chart up one view level (i.e. fed in more data) and it worked. Thank you for responding.